# Disable Checkstyle rule for class names matching pattern

Tags: java, checkstyle

For classes ending with "**Setup", the default format rule of ClassName should be replaced with a rule allowing inner class names to start with a lowercase letter - if it extends another class.
How can I do this?

A concrete example:

```
class MyExampleSetup {

  // valid, turn off ClassName check
  static class myInnerClass extends MyInnerClass() {....}
  // valid, normal class name Check
  static class MyOtherInnerClass () {....}
}
```

Comment: Why oh why would you want to do that? It's a universally accepted convention to make class names start with an uppercase letter. Just respect the convention.

Comment: Its being used for configuration of the extended class. In the inner classes, some properties are overridden and configuration-dependent wireing ist done. There's some "magic" in the background ;) But its not the point of the question, be assured I know what I'm doing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, that is impossible out of the box. What you are really asking for is a modification of behavior for one check (`TypeName`). The only way of implementing such a thing is by implementing your own [custom check](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html).

<sub>(Like the previous posters, I must urge you to consider using annotations for the background magic instead of relying on the naming convention. But that wasn't your question of course.)</sub>